# Do we need a 'big list' question on Anti virus softwares?

Tags: discussion

Okay, I will confess - **"Linux distros are NOT VIRUS(malware) prone"**. But that need not mean - "Linux distros don't get viruses(or malwares) at all". [They might get affected by viruses(or malwares)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware) - Ubuntu included. But there isn't many questions on Ask Ubuntu about Anti Virus softwares for Ubuntu([This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed) one just talks about the 'Viruses' and not about 'Anti virus Software'). So **here is my question: Shouldn't we have a [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) question on various Anti virus softwares as we have for [Application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available), [Backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools), [DEs and sheels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) and the like?**

Though we don't necessarily need an Anti virus software for Linux distros(Ubuntu included), we need to take into account every eventuality, one of those eventualities being 'A virus(or malware) affected Ubuntu'. So to have the question or not? Need some community consensus.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a great idea to make such a posting as running an antivirus product can be a great way to **help** secure one's system. Not everyone wants antivirus but for those who do this post could be very helpful I imagine. Most of the time people against running antivirus on Linux base their argument on the lack of **known** viruses for Linux, but the key word there is known. It's also important to keep in mind that over time that status will likely change as the user-base grows, and just because a virus can't infect your system because perhaps it's targeting Windows doesn't mean you want to unknowingly store it on your Linux system like some kind of sleeper agent waiting to infiltrate your dual-boot, or get attached to some email you send to a friend.

Such a posting will probably get lots of views since "antivirus for Ubuntu" is one of the first things new users Google when switching to Ubuntu at least that's how it was for me. My only concern would be making sure answers state whether the product in question scans for both Linux and Windows viruses, as if you read the fine print I've often discovered that many of the commonly recommended products actually only scan for Windows viruses, not Linux ones. Perhaps that has changed since last I checked as it was quite some time ago. To date the only product I know of available for Ubuntu that scans for Linux viruses is made by F-prot, though I can't remember the exact name of the program and I was never able to find out how big their virus signature database was.

Comment: Thanks for your support! But I am waiting for others too.

Answer (score 2):

There are **loads** of questions about viruses and preventative measures on Ubuntu.
I've answered several.

As for whether we should start a software-recommendation like thread, like one of the three questions you've mentioned... Did you read those questions? Look at them again, you'll see something along the lines of:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site,** so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will be closed per the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Probably thats why I didn't *ask* a similar software recommendation question! But asking if I can ask it in AU! Will be obliged if you could give links to those questions and answers you are referring to.

Comment: BTW I am not talking about 'Viruses and preventative measures', but talking about the aftermath of a virus attack: that is killing it after it comes and for that i will need a anti virus software and to choose one I need that question in AU!

Comment: Dealing with the aftermath is almost always going to depend on the specific virus. [See this example](http://askubuntu.com/a/436877/449). Not even existing antivirus programs claim to be good at undoing an infection after it's happened.

Comment: Ok. I read your blog post too! It was nice. Your stand also seems good one to me. But I will have to wait a bit more I suppose(at least a couple of days) so that the *community* can tell. Thanks for your post BTW!